# Joining multiple tables with one to many relationship

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql, join

I have 3 tables:

```
maintable(id, serialno, col3, col4, col5, ..., col10)

table1(t1_id, serialno, t1_type, t1_color)

table2(t2_id, serialno, t2_base, t2_price)
```

maintable's Primary Key is id and serialno is UNIQUE.
Table1's Primary Key is t1_id and table2's is t2_id.
Table1 and Table2 serialno are Foreign Keys that reference MainTable's serialno.

maintable has a one to many relationship with both table1 and table2.

What I want to do is join these 3 tables in a DataTable.

I first thought that it would be simple and I tried: "SELECT * FROM maintable INNER JOIN table1 ON maintable.serialno = table1.serialno INNER JOIN table2 ON maintable.serialno= table2.serialno WHERE maintable.id = 200";

The problem with the result is that if table1 has 3 rows and table2 has 4 rows then my DataTable becomes 12 rows(3x4). What I want to do in this instance is just get 4 rows.

table1 and table2 columns don't have anything to do with each other and they only have to match maintable's serialno.

In case that I'm not being understood, I want to select the rows of table1 and table2 that match maintable's serialno and add them to the right of maintable without them getting duplicated.

Edit: Sorry, I had written accountno instead of serialno in some cases.

Comment: Wait a minute, there are 3 rows in maintable with  maintable.id = 200. And table2 has 4 rows that matches these 3 maintable rows. How do you want to extract data from the 3 x 4 = 12 rows you get?

Comment: There is only 1 row in maintable with maintable.id = 200. Table1 has 3 rows that match serialno and Table2 has 4. What I ultimately want to do is display the columns of table1 that match serialno and the same for table2. Table1 and Table2 don't have any relationship between them that I need. I could do it in separate SQL queries but I'm trying to do it in one big DataTable because I will have 3 or 4 more tables similar to table1 and table2. I don't know if this is even possible.

Comment: How do you want to get 4 rows when table1 has 3, table2 has 4 rows and get data from both tables? It will be at least 7rows

Comment: 7 rows is fine. Now I get 12 which means that the rows are multiplied and when I add more tables the DataTable will get really big. If rows are just added there's no problem.

Comment: If both table columns where same then it could be done with union. Now you need 2 separate selects

Comment: @Reniuz Thanks. Maybe that's the only way to do it after all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM
maintable m
INNER JOIN (
SELECT t1.serialno, t1.t1_type, t1.t1_color, null as t2_base, null as t2_price
FROM table1 t1
UNION 
SELECT t2.serialno, null as t1_type, null as t1_color, t2.t2_base, t2.t2_price
FROM table2 t2
) t ON m.serialno = t.serialno
ORDER BY m.serialno
```

This will do what you're asking for: return number of rows in t1 + number of rows in t2, rather than rows in t1 x number of rows in t2. [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/f5967/10/0). This may not perform so hot if you have a large amount of data.

Now that you know how it's done, don't do it.

The real question is *why is this a requirement?* What are you really trying to accomplish here? This is not a meaningful way to combine the data from the two child tables, given their relationships. T1 and t2 are different tables and not keyed to each other for a reason: they aren't meant to combine their data like this.

The only new data I can imagine extracting from this kind of query is the total count of rows in both t1 and t2 for a given serial number. But there are *much* better ways to get this information than selecting the rows like this. If you need both t1 and t2 data and duplicates are throwing you off, odds are good that you should be making two separate SELECT statements instead of trying to combine everything.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: What I ultimately want to do as I said, is have 6-7 tables that are all referencing one key in the main table(serialno) and display their columns in a page. I am trying to figure out the best way to do it and I figured that instead of doing an sql select query for each table, the best way would be to join them all in one big DataTable and then get the records I want from there. If that's not the optimum solution please guide me in the right way. Thanks!

Comment: @user4483037 The right way to do it is to use separate select statements for each SQL table, create your list of objects in the application, and fill their properties with the data from the different SQL queries. Your application can do this ***much*** more efficiently than the database can put all the tables together inside one SQL query. When I say "may not perform so hot with large data sets" that really means "this would lose a race against a snail running backward in a production environment".

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    maintable.accountno
FROM
    maintable
    INNER JOIN table1 ON
        maintable.accountno = table1.accountno
    INNER JOIN table2 ON
        maintable.accountno = table2.accountno
WHERE
    maintable.id = 200
GROUP BY
    maintable.accountno
```

Comment: The original query has select *, i.e all columns from all 3 tables.

Comment: if you want to get every column then how do you expect it to only returns 4 rows (unless you want to use aggregate)?